# Unrecognized maven.config entries

Tags: maven, maven-3

I receive the following exception when running a test in a Community Project:

```
org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException: Unrecognized maven.config entries: []
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.cli(MavenCli.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I've tried adding up -X -e to provide some more information however it didn't help. The error itself is not very clear on the source of the issue: the pom.xml file? settings.xml? some properties missing ?
Note: I'm using Maven 3.3.3.
Do you have any clue?

Comment: Have you checked if there are some LF/NL in the file?Furthermore can you show you `maven.config` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that the error disappears if I use maven 3.3.9.
Before that I was using a maven 3.3.3 version. Hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 4):

This error can occur since Maven 3.9.0. Maven changed the format of the `maven.config` file so that [each entry must be on a new line](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7684). To fix the issue, either add newlines to `maven.config` or use the new `MAVEN_ARGS` environment variable. See the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html) for more details.

(This answer has been added as this is the top hit for the error message. My error was `Unrecognized maven.config file entries: [ -B -DtrimStackTrace=false]` which is subtly different to the OP.)

Comment: Can we pass a plugin goal inside that file? I see it as an example when using [MAVEN_ARGS](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#maven_args-environment-variable). So I have a single line with `dependency:build-classpath`, but I get `Unrecognized maven.config entries`.

Answer (score 2):

As of Maven version 3.9.0 the flags on maven.config must be on separate lines.
To fix it:
edit your maven.config to have each flag on it's own line, make sure to also delete any trailing spaces!

For example, change this:

```
-V -Dbuildtime.output.log
```

to (no trailing spaces):

```
-V
-Dbuildtime.output.log
```

the maven.config file can be found under the .mvn/ folder in your project directory